# How to know the name of the last command that was executed?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say we run this script on Linux:

```
/tmp/start.sh
```

After running it, is there any way to retrieve the name of the last command executed?

expected output

```
start.sh
```

Comment: Do you mean the last commnd to be executed or specifically the last shell script? If you run `/tmp/start.sh; ls` will you want `ls` as output or `start.sh`?

Comment: yes I mean - the last command that executed

Comment: And do you need to get it in an interactive shell session or do you need to use it in a script?

Comment: actually I want to run another script after start.sh , for example /tmp/final.sh   and this script must to know what is the last script that was run so meanwhile I do that - /tmp/final.sh start.sh , but I prefer not use that argument

Comment: @yael Huh? Could you elaborate on what it is that you _actually_ want to do, exactly? Please do so in the question itself.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. This seems like an AB question. That is you are trying to do A, can see that you can do it via B, and ask how to do B. It may be easier to just do A.

Comment: very simple - we want to run another script after the previous script that will know the name of the script that was run before that all!

Comment: It really isn't simple. For one thing, how do you define previous? What if another user ran something in a different session? What if the same user ran something but in a different session (e.g. another terminal)? Which command should be found then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using history expansion in an interactive `bash` shell:

```
$ /some/path/script.sh
```

```
$ printf 'Basename of last command line: %s\n' "$(basename "!!")"
printf 'Basename of last command line: %s\n' "$(basename "/some/path/script.sh")"
Basename of last command line: script.sh
```

The `!!` is a history expansion event designator, which will be replaced by the last command.  See the "HISTORY EXPANSION" section in your `bash` manual.

Note that `!!` will expand to the full command line.

---

In a shell script, you always know what the previous script was called, because you just typed it in.

```
/some/path/script.sh

echo 'script.sh just finished'
```

Comment: Note also that this will only work in an interactive shell.